# Python formatting for table

Tags: python, format

I am trying to print something to look like this

```
   0  1  2  3  
   ------------
 0|A  A  A  A  
 1|A  A  A  A  
 2|A  A  A  A  
 3|A  A  A  A
```

and this is my code for it:

```
def pretty_print (board):
  for i in range(-2,len(board)):
    if (i==-2):
        print ("   ",end= "")
        for k in range(len (board[1])):
            print(f"{k:<3}", end ="")
    if i==-1:
        print ("\n  ","-"*(len(board[i])*3))
    if (i>-1):
        print(f"\n{i:>2.0f}|", end= "")
        for j in range (len(board[i])):
            print (board[i][j],end ="  ")
print()
print()
```

pretty_print([['A']*4]*4)

but for some reason I am getting a line space between the line with the '-----' characters and the actual table. How do I get rid of that line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm... I just added `end=""` in line 8, and it worked for me:

```py
def pretty_print (board):
  for i in range(-2,len(board)):
    if (i==-2):
        print ("   ",end= "")
        for k in range(len (board[1])):
            print(f"{k:<3}", end ="")
    if i==-1:
        print ("\n  ","-"*(len(board[i])*3), end="")
    if (i>-1):
        print(f"\n{i:>2.0f}|", end="")
        for j in range (len(board[i])):
            print (board[i][j],end ="  ")
print()
print()
pretty_print([['A']*4]*4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the same with underscore and not hyphen. Hyphen usually produces lines like '-------' underscore produces '___________'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).